# AWS Cloudformation Error when using Fn::Join with a parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am attempting to create an s3 bucket using cloudformation and tag on an arbitrary username at the end that is pulled from a user defined parameter. Below, I have defined the s3 resource.

```
"S3Bucket" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::S3::Bucket",
      "Properties" : {
          "BucketName" : {
              "Fn::Join" :[
                  "-", [
                      "test-bucket", 
                      { 
                        "ref": "User"
                      }
                    ]
                ]
            }
      }
```

I used [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-join.html) as a resource however I get the following error message from cloudfromation:

> Template validation error: Template error: every Fn::Join object requires two parameters, (1) a string delimiter and (2) a list of strings to be joined or a function that returns a list of strings (such as Fn::GetAZs) to be joined.

I seem to have both the delimiter and list of strings described in the message. Even if I pass multiple strings, it still throws the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update `ref` to `Ref`, so that cloudformation can recognise function and replace it by string value accordingly.

```
"S3Bucket" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::S3::Bucket",
  "Properties" : {
      "BucketName" : {
          "Fn::Join": [
              "-", [
                  "test-bucket", 
                  { 
                    "Ref": "User"
                  }
                ]
            ]
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I missed that one